# connect two devices peer-to-peer without opening ports on routers

Tags: networking, p2p

I have developed an application that needs to connect two or more devices in a peer-to-peer connection.
Right now it runs smoothly on a local network, where the two devices can see each other and they communicate perfectly.

Now I want to do the same thing but over the internet. I need that two devices can talk each other on a peer-to-peer connection, but without the need to open ports on each router.

Can I do it? Torrent works this way or there is something I'm missing here?

Thanks in regards for your answers.